# How DocumentDB indexes existing documents with new index?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

I have 70k documents. I create a new index. Call explain("executionStats") with newindex field in match condition shows following:

[image]

Or it may take some time? But it was created 8 h ago. Can I somehow check progress of indexing?

Comment: How big is the entire DB?

Comment: 70k but i found that if i use NUUID("") it call caollscan if simple string like "dd25dadc-6b22-4f81-995b-2cce698a111a" it use IXSCAN

Comment: db.collection_name.getIndexes() will show the current indexes, if you see your index, it was built. I don't understand your latest comment, what values do you have for the indexed field and what is the query you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using $elemMatch? If so, documentdb will default to a collscan: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/functional-differences.html#functional-differences.indexes

Comment: Index support for $elemMatch was added in DocumentDB 5.0 - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/release-notes.html#release-notes.3.1.2023